# Resharper 5 plugin creation

Tags: plugins, resharper

I'm looking to create a plugin for resharper 5. I looked through their site and didn't find any information about where to begin. So, where do I begin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at http://resharperpowertoys.codeplex.com for links and sample plugins. You can also take a look

http://hadihariri.com/blogengine/post/2010/01/12/Writing-plug-ins-for-ReSharper-Part-1-of-Undefined.aspx

Part 2 is coming soon.